# Login details in CSV file with number of thread counts in jmeter

Tags: performance, csv, jmeter, functional-testing

I set CSV file in jmeter via CSV data Set Config this file contains 1 username and password.
The number of threads I set are 2.

When I run my test in jmeter it passes for only 1 thread and failed for another. I then added another line with same username/password in the CSV file and run the test(with 2 same username/password and 2 threads). My all tests passes

So do I need to set up username/password in CSV file with same number of thread counts(Even when I am using same username/password)?

Answer (score 1):

What is your test plan structure?

I guess that you need to add [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) **as a child** of your request

Given following test plan structure:

csv file containing one line: test

- Thread Group (2 threads, no ramp-up, 1 iteration)
- HTTP Request (host: google.com, Path: /, Parameters: q=${query}
- CSV Data Set Config (as a child of HTTP Request, Filename: path to csv file, Variable names: query, everything else - defaults)

In [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Listener I can see both threads sending "test" query

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I tried to add CSV Data Set Config as a chid of HTTP Request but no luck. It is still failing on second login.

Comment: CSV Data Set Config is always "global" per thread group. It doesn't matter which child it is within that thread group. p.s. I don't know an answer for the op question. I thought always, once the thread number exceeds the csv lines it just starts again in that file - which means it should always take your one line. Maybe look for hints here: http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-looping-2-csv-files/ have you set "Recycle on EOF" to true?